# Spring injecting Properties on jar

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a web-project with jersey that is trying to use a reusable jar. This is my jersey project exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=endpoints)}
```

appContext for the integration jar:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <util:properties id="endpoints" location="classpath:endpoints-${environment}.properties"/>

</beans>
```

My java class that should receive that property:

```
@Component
public class IntegrationService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("endpoints")
    private Properties endpoints;

    public String get(String key) {
        return endpoints.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT** If I remove the `Qualifier` and make sure that the attribute name is the same as the property id, then we're ok with the exceptions. But the problem is... I try to get my keys and I get null.

**SOLUTION**: Renamed the applicationContext from my jar, and:

```
<import resource="integration-applicationContext.xml"/>
```

Comment: How do you load the *appContext for the integration jar* ?

Comment: good question. I didnt. How do I do that?

Comment: I guess that's the answer for my problem @SergeBallesta

Comment: Please make that an answer so I can mark as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must import the appContext for the integration jar in your main application context.